# Force blocking read after EAGAIN?

Tags: c, nonblocking, file-descriptor, posix-api

I have a file descriptor that is open for reading which may be non-blocking. What I need to do is simply read all data until reaching EOF and write that data to a writable file descriptor. As the process that performs this copying is not "aware" of anything that is going on around it, I don't think that I can do something useful while waiting for data, and I don't want to use a `while` loop (while `errno` is not `EAGAIN`) because I think that it would be wasteful. Is there a way to block or otherwise suspend execution of the copying process until data becomes available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your other answer simply unsets `O_NONBLOCK`, which sets the file back to blocking.  That's perfectly fine, if that works in your situation; but if not, you can use `select()` to block until your non-blocking file descriptor is readable.

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 7 of the Linux SCSI Generic (sg) HOWTO gives [an example](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/fcntl.html) of how to do this:

```
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags & (~O_NONBLOCK));
```